# Jsoup check if login was successful

Tags: android, jsoup

Here is the deal. One of my activities requires for ID and password input to login. How can i check if login was successful ( the main idea is to check if such account exists, but I do NOT have access to database to check for it. So I need an alternative : if I'm able to login - thats OK, if not - drop alertDialog with message and let user try to input right data). How can i do that with Jsoup ?

Here is the piece of code I'm using in AsyncTaskLoader to do login and retrieve some data :

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(URL)
                .data("id", paramID, "password", paramPassword)
                .timeout(10000)
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();

        String cookie = response.cookie("JSESSIONID");

            Document document = Jsoup.connect(targetURL)
                    .cookie("JSESSIONID", cookie)
                    .get();
```

Any ideas how to do that ? Thanks :)

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: Issue is that I dont know how to check if login was successful. You see, I ho not have control of server, so I cannot check if such user (paramID, paramPassword) exist in the database. So, if I'm able to login with these parameters - user exists and thats ok, but if not - i dont want to let the user to go to another activity. So the question is : how to check if login was successful (the user with these parameters logged in after sending POST, o just sent POST, but login was unsuccessful because of incorrect ID / Password).

Comment: I don't understand. You have apparently no way of testing the login result, but you want to know if the user was logged in? What's with th `JSESSIONID` cookie?

Comment: Well, I have my own account, so with JSESSION cookie I'm maintaining session for redirection to another page for data scrape, but before that there is LoginActivity, where some user inputs their ID and password and saves it to SharedPreferences. So I wanted to check if user can login to the website with these name-value pairs. Cause I dont want to let the user try to connect to webpage in other activity with incorrect ID/ pass.

Comment: having absolutely no idea as to what this website you are trying to log in looks, it seems a bit complicated to give you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question as I understand it: you want to test to see if the user name and password you have used is valid.

You need to know two things:

1. What the subsequent page looks like in event of a successful login.
2. What the subsequent page looks like in event of an unsuccessful login.

So, use this:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(targetURL)
    .cookie("JSESSIONID", cookie)
    .get();
```

This is going to take some investigation on your part. You need to inspect the two different pages and find a single element that exists in one or both of them that will allow you to distinguish between a successful login and a failed login.

For example, if you're lucky, you might be able to compare the titles of the document like this:

```
if (document.title().contains("Login Successful or whatever")){
    // DO SOMETHING
} else if (document.title().contains("Login Unsuccessful or something else")){
    // DO SOMETHING ELSE
};
```

Like I said, that's if you're lucky. Otherwise you're going to have to go investigate and examine the respective html pages and figure out a convenient element to use to test the two pages for.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yea.. yesterday I did that with titles. I guess it's the only way, when you do not have access to database. Thanks :)